# Excel VBA - Macro that runs for entire range of cell

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have this below macro code that performs a transpose a range of cells.

```
Sub Macro45()
'
' Macro45 Macro
' r3
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
Range("F2:G8").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("H2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

I am trying to see how could I repeat the same process for entire range of rows. My dataset has about 10000 rows and I want to perform the same tasks over the entire range.

Comment: Hi, 1) where would you paste the next rows? 2) do you need to paste the format or just the values? 3) what do you define as entire rows? 4) do you always copy two rows of data? 5) Some sample input data and desired output would help

Comment: @RicardoDiaz, I selected the range `F2:G8` and pasted the output in H2. Similarly I am trying to copy cells from range `F9:G15` and paste it in cell `F9` and so on.. Yes I am trying to copy two rows of data

Comment: Sorry, I meant two columns. Pasting the second data range in F2 would overwrite some cells. Also, do you need to paste formats?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz, sorry if I mistyped. column H is all blank. I am selecting cells from range `F2:G8` and pasting in  `H2` similarly selected `F9:G15` and paste in  `H9`. Moreover I am transposing and pasting the content so basically converting data in rows into columns..

Comment: Won't 'Paste Special' -> transpose do the trick?

Comment: @jivko, that is exactly what I am trying to do. I did for first range of rows (`F2:G8` and pasted it in `H2`) but I am trying to do for the next 1000 set of rows so trying to get a macro that would automate this for me.

Comment: Why don;t you transpose the whole range instead of in chunks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you taking particular steps of 7 rows. So maybe try:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly

    'Find last used row
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

    'Step through data and transpose values
    For x = 2 To lr Step 7
        .Cells(x, 8).Resize(2, 7).Value = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(x, 6), .Cells(x + 6, 7)).Value)
    Next x

End With

End Sub
```

---

Or if you really interested in copy-paste values and format:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly

    'Find last used row
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

    'Step through data
    For x = 2 To lr Step 7
        .Range(.Cells(x, 6), .Cells(x + 6, 7)).Copy
        .Cells(x, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    Next x

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution:

```
Sub main()

    Dim rngSrc As Range
    Set rngSrc = Range("F2:G8")

    While (rngSrc.Cells(1, 1).Value2 <> "")
       transpose rngSrc
       Set rngSrc = rngSrc.Offset(7, 0)
    Wend
End Sub


Sub transpose(rngSrc As Range)

    rngSrc.Copy
    rngSrc.Cells(1, 2).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, transpose:=True

End Sub
```